# How can i decrease dotnet.wasm size

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor

I Have published blazor web assembly project in .net core 6 preview 7

now my dotnet.wasm file size is very large
and this has 64mb and its take a few minutes to download and run application
[In this image you can see the dotnet.wasm file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uvex.png)

- How can i decrease its size!?

> i have published AOT Compilation and disabled globalization and other useless peace

Comment: AoT _increases_ the size.

Comment: How much is it without aot?

Comment: Yeah this true aot is increases the size but what's the benefits of blazor aot!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly to enable Brotli compression. Afterwards, you can optionally delete the uncompressed as well as the `*.gz` compressed files. That way, you can reduce the overall size a lot, down to a few megabytes.

Comment: yeah it's good way to reduce size but i have enabled AoT compilation and it's increased my dotnet.wasm file size now I have one question!! How can i solve size in AoT Mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Lazy Load Assembly feature available on .net 6 (and 5).

Look at Microsoft official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You can decrease a lot your startup size and load time.

Comment: yeah I'm seen this but Assemblies in my project is Used everywhere and I don't know how to use this feature

Answer (score 1):

Add `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` to your .csproj (inside **PropertyGroup**). Trimming will do most of the size reduction for you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options

Comment: it is not enable as default!?